# pluginlib Tutorial - polygon_base.h not found

Tags: ros, tutorial, pluginlib, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I'm facing an error when trying to build the [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/pluginlib/Tutorials/Writing%20and%20Using%20a%20Simple%20Plugin) on the pluginlib.
I updated my `CMakeLists.txt`, `package.xml` and created a `polygon_loader.xml` as described in the tutorial, but when I try to build the project, it fails stating that in `[my_workspace]/pluginlib_tutorials_/src/polygon_loader.cpp` the included header file `pluginlib_tutorials_/polygon_base.h` could not be found.

The funny thing is, if I change my `CMakeLists.txt` by adding the line

```
 target_link_libraries(polygon_loader polygon_plugins)
```

my `polygon_loader.cpp` is fine, but my `polygon_plugins.cpp` throws the previous mentioned error. It seems I missed some configuring in the ROS toolchain I guess. Could please someone help me out?

Thanks in advance,
Roberto

P.S.: Here are the relevant fragments, if something is missing, please ask!

**My file structure:**

> catkin_ws_plugins/
> -> build
> -> devel
> -> src
> --> `CMakeList.txt`
> --> pluginlib_tutorials_
> ---> `CMakeLists.txt`
> ---> `package.xml`
> ---> `polygon_plugins.xml`
> ---> include
> ----> pluginlib_tutorials_
> -----> `polygon_base.h`
> -----> `polygon_plugins.h`
> ---> src
> -----> `polygon_loader.cpp`
> -----> `polygon_plugins.cpp`

**catkin_ws_plugins/src/pluginlib_tutorials_/CMakeLists.txt:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(pluginlib_tutorials_)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
    pluginlib
    roscpp
)
catkin_package()
include_directories(
    ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
add_library(polygon_plugins src/polygon_plugins.cpp)
add_executable(polygon_loader src/polygon_loader.cpp)
target_link_libraries(polygon_loader ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

**catkin_ws_plugins/src/pluginlib_tutorials_/package.xml (only the changes):**

```
<export>
    <pluginlib_tutorials_ plugin="${prefix}/polygon_plugins.xml" />
</export>
```

**catkin_ws_plugins/src/pluginlib_tutorials_/polygon_plugins.xml:**

```
<library path="lib/libpolygon_plugins">
    <class type="polygon_plugins::Triangle" base_class_type="polygon_base::RegularPolygon">
         <description>This is a triangle plugin</description>
    </class>
    <class type="polygon_plugins::Square" base_class_type="polygon_base::RegularPolygon">
         <description>This is a square plugin</description>
    </class>
</library>
```

Last but not least the line where the error occurs in
**catkin_ws_plugins/src/pluginlib_tutorials_/src/polygon_loader.cpp**

```
#include <pluginlib_tutorials_/polygon_base.h>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/129881/pluginlib-tutorial---polygon_base.h-not-found/) by [bnm-rc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11866/bnm-rc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 22 on 2014-02-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to add your local include directory to the `include_directories` in your CMakeLists.txt

It shold look more like:

```
include_directories(
    include
    ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0